# Why do I get a black rectangle instead of my external picture?

Tags: graphics

I write some of my network notes in TeX. I wanted to make a table, and inside it insert an image:

[image: see it here].

I wrote a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{3cm}m{3cm}m{5cm}}
\toprule
Configuration for ... & Commands & Topology\\
\midrule
PPP: CHAP, PAP & \#sh int se 0/0/0  & \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{chappap.png}\\
 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But instead of my network topology image, I see only this: [image: black picture].

I don't know what is wrong, cause **my image is 100% in the same dir, as my *.tex file.**

**EDIT:**

Changed my code as @Jubobs suggested, now everything is as I wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{m{3cm}m{3cm}m{5cm}}
    \toprule
    Configuration for ... & Commands & Topology\\
    \midrule
    PPP: CHAP, PAP & \#sh int se 0/0/0  & \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=4cm]{chappap.png}\\
     & & \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: That's what happens when the `demo` option is passed to the `graphicx` package: all external pictures are replaced by black rectangles. Do you also get the black rectangle *without* that option?

Comment: @Jubobs: Geez, didnt think about that it can be 'the problem' here. Thanks :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's what happens when the `demo` option is passed to the `graphicx` package (as in your MWE). That option is described in the `graphicx` manual:

> `demo`: Instead of inserting an image file `\includegraphics` draws a 150 pt by 100 pt rectangle unless other dimensions are specified manually.

If you want the actual external picture to be included by `\includegraphics{...}`,

1. disable the `demo` option,
2. make sure that the path to that picture specified in `\includegraphics{...}` is correct.

Note that you will get an error from LaTeX, not merely a black rectangle, if the path to your external picture is incorrect.

Comment: How can I disable the demo option in the graphix package, if I deleted it, the file won't run?